# How do I get a Kubernetes secret file?

Tags: kubectl

I created a Kubernetes secret file from a file with this command:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic appconfig --from-file appsecrets.json
```

How do I get the file?  If I run `kubectl get secret -o yaml`, then I see base64 encoded text.

Answer (score 1):

Two examples of downloading a file containing a dot in the key(filename).

```
kubectl get secrets appconfig -o "jsonpath={.data['appsecrets\.json']}" | base64 -d > appsecrets.json
kubectl get secrets appconfig -o 'go-template={{index .data "appsecrets.json"}}' | base64 -d > appsecrets.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (one-liner) is:

```
kubectl get secret appconfig -o jsonpath='{.data.appsecrets\.json}'|base64 -d
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ kubectl get secret appconfig -o 'go-template={{index .data "appsecrets.json"}}' | base64 -d
```